# VHDL using a custom package

Tags: package, vhdl

I've made a custom package and tried to use it in on my code. for some reason, it doesn't recognize my custom types i've declared in the package.

```
library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
library work;
    use work.lt_package.all;



--use lt_package.db_array;
--use work.lt_package.hb_ctl_state;
--use work.lt_package.lb_ctl_state;
--use work.lt_package.t_state;

-- synopsys translate_off
--library MACHXO2L;
--use MACHXO2L.components.all;
-- synopsys translate_on
entity LC_top is port
(
    reset                   : in  std_logic;
    clk                     : in  std_logic;
    sdi_bit_vector          : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    red_leds_out            : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    green_leds_out          : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    sclk                    : out std_logic;
    db_out                  : out db_array;
    conv_out                : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
);
```

my package is:

```
library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
package lt_package is
end package;

package body lt_package is
type t_state is (clk_wait_op , lt_wait_op , conversion_op);
type hb_ctl_state is ( hba , hbb);
type lb_ctl_state is (lba , lbb , dlu);
type db_array is array (4 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
end package;
```

whenever I compile the code it tells me that db_array is not declared although it's clearly in the package. any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Declarations in a a package declaration would be visible through a use clause, while those in a package body would not. There's no way to reference declarations select in an unnamed secondary unit (package body) with a selected name in a use clause The declarations found in a package declaration may be.. IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.8 Package bodies "Items declared in the body of a package cannot be made visible outside of the package body." Note the second `end package;` should be `end package body;` or just `end;`. The reserved word `body` must be present if the reserved word `package` is present.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your types in the package declaration area (i.e. between "`package lt_package is`" and "`end_package`", and before the package body, for them to be visible outside of the package.

If you had functions or procedures in your package, their declarations would go in the declaration area (analogous to function prototypes in many programming languages), and the actual function definition would reside in the package body.